# How know the following subset of $\Bbb{F}^3_2$ is subspace of $\Bbb{F}^3_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\Bbb{F}^3_2$ is defined as the binary system. i.e. $1+0=1$, $1+1=0$

The subset if $\{(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$

It is said to be not closed under addition because $(1,0,0)+(1,1,1)=(0,1,1)$ is not in the subset.

I think I have an understanding issue here. Since $(0,1,1)=(1,0,0)+(1,1,1)$, so it's the linear combination of this two vectors in subset, so why is $(0,1,1)$ not closed under addition? I have the same question for closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{F}^3_2$ is closed under addition by definition if for every $x,y$ elements from $S$, $x+y \in S$ is true. 
Similarly $S$ is closed under multiplication if for every $c$ scalar from the field under the vector space - in this case this field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ - and for every $x \in S$ the element $c x$ is in $S$.
What can you say about $S = \{(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$? Is it closed under addition or multiplication?

Following the same line of thought can you say something in general about an arbitrary $S\subseteq V$ set being closed under multiplication where $V$ is an arbitrary vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$?